# Solving Schroedinger Equation for the electronic energies of the Molecular Ion Hydrogen H2+ in the Elliptic coordinate system

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, differential-equations, quantum-mechanics

**Electronic Energies of Molecular Ion Hydrogen $H_2^{+}$**

$r_1$ is the distance between the proton $1$ and the electron.

$r_2$ is the distance between the proton $2$ and the electron.

$R$ is the distance between the two protons, fixed parameter in Born-Oppenheimer approximation.

Schroedinger's Equation:

$$
\hat{H} \Psi = E_{el} \Psi
$$

$$
-\frac{{\hbar}^2}{2 m_e} \Delta \Psi -\frac{e^2}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0} \left(\frac{1}{r_1}+\frac{1}{r_2}\right)\Psi = E_{el} \Psi
$$

Atomic Units:

$$
a_0=\frac{4 \pi \varepsilon_0 \hbar^2}{m_e e^2} = 0.5291 *10^{-10} m
$$

$$
E_h=\frac{\hbar^2}{m_e a_0^2}=27.21 eV
$$

$$
\Delta \Psi + \frac{2}{a_0}\left(\frac{1}{r_1}+\frac{1}{r_2}\right)\Psi=-2 \frac{E_{el}}{E_h a_0^2} \Psi
$$

We introduce the adimensional parameters $ r= \frac{R}{a_0} $ and $ \varepsilon = \frac{E_{el}}{E_h} $

Elliptic coordinate system:

$ \xi = \frac{r_1 + r_2}{R} $ , $ \eta=\frac{r_1 - r_2}{R} $ and $ \phi $ is the angle between the position vector of the electron and the $xy$ plane.

The Laplacian operator will become:

$$ \Delta =\frac{4}{R^2 (\xi^2 - \eta^2) } \left[\frac{\partial }{\partial \xi} (\xi^2 -1)\frac{\partial }{\partial \xi}+\frac{\partial }{\partial \eta} (1-\eta^2)\frac{\partial }{\partial \eta}+\frac{\xi^2 - \eta^2}{(\xi^2-1)(1-\eta^2)}\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial \phi^2}\right] $$

then we obtain:

$ \left[\frac{\partial }{\partial \xi} (\xi^2 -1)\frac{\partial }{\partial \xi}+\frac{\partial }{\partial \eta} (1-\eta^2)\frac{\partial }{\partial \eta}+\frac{\xi^2 - \eta^2}{(\xi^2-1)(1-\eta^2)}\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial \phi^2}\right] \Psi + 2r\xi \Psi = - \frac{1}{2} r^2\varepsilon (\xi^2 - \eta^2)\Psi $

We can separate the variables using $ \Psi = \Xi_{\xi} H_{\eta} \Phi_{\phi} $ so we can obtain three indipendent differential equations:

$$ \frac{\partial }{\partial \xi} (\xi^2 -1)\frac{\partial \Xi }{\partial \xi} + \left(2r\xi+A+\frac{1}{2}r^2 \varepsilon \xi^2 - \frac{\Lambda^2}{\xi^2-1}\right)\Xi=0 $$

$$ \frac{\partial }{\partial \eta} (1-\eta^2)\frac{\partial H }{\partial \eta} + \left(-A-\frac{1}{2}r^2 \varepsilon \eta^2 - \frac{\Lambda^2}{1-\eta^2}\right)H=0 $$

$$ \frac{\partial^2 \Phi }{\partial \phi^2} = - \Lambda^2 \Phi $$

where A is a separation parameter and $ \Lambda \in \mathbb{N} $

Focusing on the first one we can divide both members for $ \Xi $ and do this substitution: $ f_{\xi} =- \frac{1}{\Xi} \frac{\partial \Xi}{\partial \xi} $ obtaining this new differential equation:

$$ 2 \xi f + (\xi^2-1)(f'+f^2)-\left(2r\xi+A+\frac{1}{2}r^2 \varepsilon \xi^2 - \frac{\Lambda^2}{\xi^2-1}\right)=0 $$

and from now on I don't know how to move. Is there someone who knows how to solve numerically this equation?

Comment: you'll get a better response at http://physics.stackexchange.com --- there is no advanced math issue here (I removed the "quantum algebra tag")

Comment: to be honest, I thought that the advanced math issue was the numerical solution of the last equation I've written..

Comment: Crossposted to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/205265/2451

Answer (score 2):

H. Bethe discusses the numerical solution of your equations for $\Xi$ and $H$ (his eqs (58.21-22)) in §58d of [*Quantenmechanik der Ein- und Zwei-Elektronenprobleme* (1933)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-52619-0_3). So do Baber & Hassé in [*The Two Centre Problem in Wave Mechanics* (1935)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0305004100013566). (They don't use your $f_\xi$ substitution, which has the drawback of making the equation nonlinear!)